# Strange exception when logging set to trace in Play Framework 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1

I am seeing a strange exception when I turn on trace logging on my Play 2.1 with Scala project.  This exception is seen whenever I invoke a controller including the following controller which is essentially a ping:

```
object Ping extends Controller {
  def get() = Action {
    Ok("LALA")
  }
}
```

Even more frustratingly, there is nothing in the exception stack that links my code with the exception.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Below exception trace:

```
2013-02-27 09:57:24,163 [T] [] - Exception caught in Netty      
  java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to scala.Function0
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.channelDisconnected(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:50) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:573) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:366) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:399) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:716) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:89) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:472) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:333) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_41]
```

Comment: I am also seeing this bug.  We're not the only ones: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/Ehc69rULbho/xXBK4VTIRJsJ